# Problems when running User-Data in Powershell for EC2

Tags: .net, powershell, amazon-web-services, user-data

I have a script that is running in UserData in my Amazon EC2 instance.

The script does the following:

1 Creating a user

2 Adding this user to the correct groups

3 Installing an application as a service with this new user.

4 That application are now creating certificates for that user on that user

5 Running an application to set a license with the credentials for the new user. (Start-Process -Credential $mycreds)

Everything here works fine until step 5. When I try to run that application It does not work and I do not get any feedback. If I run the script manually on that computer it works.

However when I run it manually I can also see that it opens up a new command prompt when running the .exe file.

So what I suspect now is that since the EC2Config (that starts my userdata if I have understanded it correct) is running as a service with the user Local System (that is not interactive by default) it are not allowed to run that .exe file since it's starting up a new command prompt.

So I have two questions about this:

**1. Do you agree? Or am I misunderstanding something here?**

**2. Is there any workaround for me? It's not an option to not start the .exe file without the -Credential parameter and since I have that one i cant use -NoNewWindow parameter.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved this already but for what its worth:

This could be a non-interactive problem. You could diagnose confirm by redirecting std error and std out to a file:

```
-RedirectStandardError c:\temp\err.log - RedirectStandardOutput c:\temp\out.log
```

you can also try using:

```
 -WindowStyle Hidden
```